# Why does my output changes in this python code?

Tags: python

```
s = 4.999999999999999
print(int(s))
```

This prints 4, which seems fine. But when I add one more 9 at the end(that would be 16th '9') then the output comes as 5

Comment: Because floats aren't precise, and only can save about 15 significant digits.